# Append <div> to node in SVG with D3

Tags: d3.js

I have tried to add some popup messages next to nodes but it looks like anything other than SVG <text> elements won't display with append.

This works:

```
  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 16)
      .attr("dy", ".0em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });
```

But when I append a `div` instead of `text` it is not visible. Is there something I am missing here? How can I make the div visible?

Also how can I easily get the position of node so i can transfer the positioning attributes to another element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put HTML elements anywhere in an SVG, you need to enclose them in a `foreignObject` element, see [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/foreignobject-hey-youve-got-html-in-my-svg). If you enclose both the `text` element and the `foreignObject` in an SVG group (`g` element) and set the position on that, they should both show up in the same place without the need to set the same position on both.

Comment: ok so the question was another thing,i already have the g group and if i append the element i dont need to set the position, so how can i append a div? i want to modify the div later for appearance but it doesnt shows up, it is invisible

Comment: As I've said, you need to put HTML elements, such as `div`, inside a `foreignObject` element. You should be able to select and modify its attributes later using the normal selectors.

Comment: svg.append("foreignObject")
      .attr("width", 480)
      .attr("height", 500)
    .append("xhtml:div")
      .style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'")
      .html('asd');

Comment: link is referencing a completely wrong page - (basic HTML usage as opposed to d3 / SVG)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can define your html code outside of svg in its' own div.  Then append the contents by class using:

```
d3.select("#nytg-tooltip").style('top',ypos+"px").style('left',xpos+"px").style('display','block');
```

As seen in this example:

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/10/15/us/politics/swing-history.html?_r=0

[image]

Comment: THere is a good tutorial here for just that method: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-tooltips-to-d3js-graph.html