# Calculate absolute position for d3 graph nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 force layout. Each node in this force layout has a label, which is a `<div>` code(can have table inside) and should follow it all the time. I defined the `<div>`'s position to be absolute and set their position like this:

```
var updateNode = function() {
label_xOffset=10;
label_yOffset=10
this.attr("transform", function(d,i) {
    //this is where I set their position
    //d.num declare corresponding div in node_lables_divs array
    node_labels_divs[parseInt(d.num)].style("left",(d.x+label_xOffset)+"px").style("top",(d.y+label_yOffset)+"px");
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
}

function tick(e) {
     node.call(updateNode);
}
```

Everything is good now as long as I don't pan or zoom in my SVG. But I need those features too. So in my zoom function I handled it like this:

```
var zoomer = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1,10]).
    x(xScale).
    y(yScale).on("zoom", redraw);
function redraw() {
    var translation=" translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + "px,"+d3.event.translate[1]+"px)";
    d3.selectAll("div.node_lables_html").style("transform",translation)
                                        .style("-webkit-transform",translation)
                                        .style("-ms-transform",translation);
     //vis is the <g> tag that contains the whole nodes and links
     vis.attr("transform","translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"+" scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Now every thing good when I drag and pan the SVG. But it is very bad when I try to zoom in the SVG, lables are going in different direction and they are not following the nodes. I print out the `d3.event.translate` and it seems that it has different scale in times of zoom and panning. 
I also tried the d3 foreignElement but it seems that the transform attribute doesn't work for the foreignElements. How should I calculate the correct value to transform htmls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11324728/2071807) to a similar question (it's not a duplicate, quite), you need to:

- Put the div into a [`foreignObject`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/extend.html#ForeignObjectElement) SVG element (which allows arbitrary HTML inside an SVG)
- add the `foreignObject` to a group, along with anything else that needs to be with the label
- Only apply the `tranform`s to the group

Comment: Instead of creating them separately, I put them in a foreignobject with the nodes in a <g> tag. Now it is working.

Comment: Happy to help. Fancy upvoting my answer?

Comment: This code works with Firefox. I tried it with Chrome, the foreignobjects are showing but the transform doesn't apply on them. do you have any idea to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a new question to me. As a general rule, only clarifications should go in comments. Ask this as a new question and link to this one.